# Getting half a string array at random no matter array size

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, random

I am trying to create a function that takes half of the names at random and spits them back out. This is what I have currently:
 `

```
var shuffle = require('shuffle-array')

return (

  <h1>{shuffle.pick(['Kevin ','Bill ','Chuck ','Tom ','Joe ', 'Mike '], { 'picks':  2 })}</h1>

);
```

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to select half of the names or how to allow names to be added from the site instead of hardcoding them? Your question isn't clear. What have you tried?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Check out [ask] and [mcve] for tips on how to get good answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 2 hard-coded, you can get the '.length' of the array and just divide by 2 to get half.